# Flaw in UWP design: no way to make use of the supplied buffer in IInputStream.ReadAsync

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I am trying to extend IInputStream and it seems that one of the method [ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream.readasync.aspx) there is no way to write data to the given `IBuffer` and pass it back to the caller. (I believe that I have looked at most API concerning `IBuffer` such as `DataWriter`, `IRandomAccessStream`.) Am I missing something? Or is this just the flaw in the design of UWP framework? How do one implement this?

Comment: Could you further clarify your question? What do you mean "write data to the given IBuffer"?  `ReadAsync` method is used for reading not writing.

Comment: @ZORRO I want to implement a class extending `IInputStream` so I have to implement the method `ReadAsync` to return the requested data. From the class's perspective, I am writing data to the supplied `IBuffer` that the caller supplied. (From the caller's perspective, it is reading data from my class.)